# Worker threads in Node js

Tags: node.js, typescript, worker-thread

Unable to do axios calls inside worker threads

Hi,
I have a node js application and I am trying to use worker threads for one of my use case.Inside my worker thread I need to do axios call.I was not able to do that and thread is giving me error with empty error object.
Can anyone help me figure out the issue here

Answer (score 0):

Could you share a sample code? Here's a simple working code:

```js
// index.js
const { Worker } = require("worker_threads");

const worker = new Worker("./worker.js");
worker.postMessage("run!");
```

```js
// worker.js
const { parentPort } = require("worker_threads");
const Axios = require("axios");

const getRequest = async function () {
  const tiresias = await Axios({
    baseURL: "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api",
    url: "/character/1",
    method: "get",
    params: { s: "tets", min: 0.1 }
  });

  console.log(tiresias.data);
};
parentPort.once("message", (message) => getRequest());
```